# Error converting dvi file to svg to make manim text

Tags: python, manim

I just installed manim on my windows system.
I have updated MikTex before running the manim code.
I tried to output the MovingAngl example code.
After running the manim code, MikTeX gave an error saying that it needs to install something. I have confirmed the installation.
Now it seems that manim has a problem converting the dvi file to svg, but when I manually enter 0 with the command `dvisvgm -p1 26ec1c2309a05843.dvi -n -v 0`, the svg file is generated without any problems, and if after that I run the manim code again because the svg file has been generated, the work proceeds without errors and the clip is created.
How can I fix this problem?

I had first installed manim, then MikTeX. I uninstalled and reinstalled manim but it still didn't work. I also reinstalled MikTeX but it still didn't work.